# How to send email using gmail app in Delphi XE5?

Tags: android, delphi, gmail, firemonkey, delphi-xe5

It's simple: i'm trying to create an email using the gmail app for android, just like when you share something using gmail. I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: There are tons of examples available online that show how to send emails via GMail using Indy components, for example: http://www.marcocantu.com/tips/oct06_gmail.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found it:

```
procedure TfrmSendMail.CreateEmail(const Recipient, Subject, Content,
  Attachment, Attachment2: string);
var
  Intent: JIntent;
  Uri: Jnet_Uri;
  AttachmentFile: JFile;

begin
  Intent := TJIntent.Create;
  Intent.setAction(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
  Intent.setFlags(TJIntent.JavaClass.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, StringToJString(Recipient));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(Subject));
  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(Content));

  AttachmentFile := SharedActivity.getExternalFilesDir
    (StringToJString(Attachment));


  Uri := TJnet_Uri.JavaClass.fromFile(AttachmentFile);


  Intent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM,
  TJParcelable.Wrap((Uri as ILocalObject).GetObjectID));


  Intent.setType(StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));

  SharedActivity.startActivity(Intent);
end;
```

Comment: This code is misusing the `Activity.getExternalFilesDir()` method. Assuming `Attachment` is a full path to the actual file being attached, use `AttachmentFile := TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(Attachment))` instead.

Comment: Also, `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` is [documented](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_EMAIL) as expecting an **array** of string values, but you are passing it a **single** string instead.