# How to send email with attachment using default Android email app - Delphi RIO

Tags: android, delphi

Hello StackOverflow's team,

With Delphi Rio, I have an Android app whose I want to send an email with attached zip file.

Regarding to the following link, I can do this with Delphi Tokyo (devices 6.0, 8.0 and 8.1) but it doesn't work with Rio: the app closes with 8.0 + 8.1 devices without any message error. It works on my 6.0 device.

[How to send email with attachment using default Android email app - Delphi XE7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28956563/how-to-send-email-with-attachment-using-default-android-email-app-delphi-xe7)

Zip file has been created before calling CreateEmail procedure.

This link [stackoverflow.com/a/53605468/3164070](http://stackoverflow.com/a/53605468/3164070) really helped me but now I have 2 destination adresses:

- _Recipient which is OK
- //com.embarcadero.MyApp.fileprovider/external_files/MyApp/Tmpdir/TmpFile.zip which is wrong...

How can I remove the wrong adress ?

Here is my procedure:

```
procedure CreateEmailTest(const _Recipient, _Subject, _Content, _Attachment: string);
var LIntent: JIntent;
  LAuthority: JString;
  LUri: Jnet_Uri;
  JRecipient: TJavaObjectArray<JString>;
begin
  LAuthority := StringToJString(JStringToString(TAndroidHelper.Context.getApplicationContext.getPackageName) + '.fileprovider');
  LUri := TJFileProvider.JavaClass.getUriForFile(TAndroidHelper.Context, LAuthority, TJFile.JavaClass.init(StringToJString(_Attachment)));

  LIntent := TJIntent.JavaClass.init(TJIntent.JavaClass.ACTION_SEND);

  JRecipient          := TJavaObjectArray<JString>.Create(1);
  JRecipient.Items[0] := StringToJString(_Recipient);
  LIntent.removeExtra(StringToJString(_Attachment));//do not remove wrong email adress
  LIntent.removeExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL) ;//do not remove wrong email adress
  LIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_EMAIL, JRecipient);
  LIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_SUBJECT, StringToJString(_Subject));
  LIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_TEXT, StringToJString(_Content));
  LIntent.putExtra(TJIntent.JavaClass.EXTRA_STREAM, TJParcelable.Wrap((LUri as ILocalObject).GetObjectID)); // ajout de la pièce jointe
  LIntent.setDataAndType(LUri, StringToJString('vnd.android.cursor.dir/email'));

  TAndroidHelper.Activity.startActivity(LIntent);
end;
```

Regards,

Lefjucabro

Comment: I expect it will need similar treatment as the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53605468/3164070

Comment: Hi Dave, indeed it helps me. I thought I didn't have to use these units with Rio.Thx